# In Python, how do I delete directories from a set comparison? Comparing 2 sets of Directories - delete folders that do not match

Tags: python, boto

I have a directory 1 that has new files and a directory 2 that has the same files but older. I want to move any folders that do not exist in either Directory 1 or Directory 2 and ONLY save files that match both locations:

Here's my code:

```
def removeOldDirs():
    dir1 = os.listdir('/directory1')
    dir2 = os.listdir('/directory2')
    dir1 = set(dir1)
    dir2 = set(dir2)
    oldFolders = set(dir2).difference(dir1)
    os.chdir('/')
    shutil.move(oldFolders,'/old')
    print os.listdir('.')
```

I am expecting for the folder names that do not match in either directory to move to the '/old' file directory.  I am getting an error saying 
`TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, set found
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, set found`

Is there a more 'pythonic' way of doing this? Should I make a system call instead?

Comment: There's a lot going on here. Any chance you can remove some of the unnecessary context?

Comment: agreed with @robert we really need an MCVE. If you distill it out to the barest example you can, it'll probably become obvious to you what needs to be done even without an answerer on SO.

Comment: Ok - no problem give me a min. Apologize for the verbosity.

Comment: I removed all the comments - thank you robert and Adam.

Comment: I distilled my question to the exact problem I am having -- sorry for being so not on point! Thanks to the lead developer in my job for yelling at me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shutil.move takes two arguments: the src file/directory and the destination file/directory.
If you have a list (or in your case set) of files/directories, you can just do:

```
for od in oldfolders:
   shutil.move(od,"/old")
```

Comment: Thanks @Foon this is exactly what I was missing! I was overthinking the process for sure.